# Convert Access Form to Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

I have an Access file that has 4 tables. How can I convert one of the tables to an excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the ability to export tables in Access to Excel. Using Access 2007, after opening the table go to the External Data tab and in the Export block click on the Excel button (it has the icon of a table in Datasheet view with an Excel icon in front of it).

[image: Export Access to Excel]

Comment: If the access db has forms, how can I navigate to the table?

Comment: sorry i have taken so long to respond. on the left hand side of the screen in Access is there a panel that fills the window from just beneath the ribbon to the bottom on down? if yes, does it say "Forms" at the top left with a little down arrow next to double arrows pointing left at the top right? if yes again, if you click the down arrow can you select "Tables and Related Views" under "Navigate to Category"? if you answered yes again then you should now be seeing all the tables in the database.